# Redirect request for directory-name to directory-name.html with htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

On my website, when somebody requests a directory, I want it to remove the '/' and add '.html' (minus the quotes, of course).

Example:
If someone goes to `domain.com/directory/` it should redirect to `domain.com/directory.html/` and the same should stand for: `domain.com/another-directory/` should redirect to `domain.com/another-directory.html`.

I would like to place a line (or two) of code to my `htaccess` file that will make any directory (URL ending with `/`) redirect to `URL.html` (removing the `/` of course).

I would also like it to visually redirect, so the user will actually see it change to `.html`.

I'm quite a novice web programmer, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: I did use `Redirect /directory /directory.html` and that worked, but that requires a lot of extra coding, and I would much prefer one simple statement to cover all directories.

Comment: Just create a folder named `directory`, put `directory.html` into it and rename the file to `index.html`.

Comment: @Gerben Thank you, but that's not what I want. I don't want to have a bunch of index.html files. I want to have one single index.html file for my homepage, but then the indexes for each directory have different names. If I can't find another solution, though, I will use yours.

Comment: So does `/directory/` actually exist? or do you have a file `directory.html` in your document root and want to make it look like a directory?

Comment: @JonLin Well, `/directory/` exists, and I have a file `/directory.html` as well. I chose that approach to it, because thankfully your answer below worked, and this way I do not have to have several `index.html` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a bit difficult with htaccess, I assume you want to do the following:

1. If someone accesses a directory that isn't the root (simply http://domain.com/), redirect them to the directory name ending with .html
2. After the get redirected, internally rewrite the .html **back** to the directory so apache can serve the directory.

First one is straightforward:

```
# check to make sure the request isn't actually for an html file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /(.+)\.html\ HTTP
# check to make sure the request is for a directory that exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# rewrite the directory to 
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1.html [R]
```

Second part is tricky

```
# check to make sure the request IS for an html file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /(.+)\.html\ HTTP
# See if the directory exists if you strip off the .html
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2 -d
# Check for an internal rewrite token that we add
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !r=n
# if no token, rewrite and add token (so that directories with index.html won't get looped)
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html /$1/?r=n [L,QSA]
```

---

However, if what you just have is a bunch of files called `directory.html`, `directory2.html`, `directory3.html`, etc. and you want to make it so when someone enters http://domain.com/directory2/ into their address bar they get served the contents of `directory2.html`, it will be much simpler:

```
# check to make sure the request isn't actually for an html file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /(.+)\.html\ HTTP
# check to see if the html file exists (need to do this to strip off the trailing /)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$ 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.html -f
# rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1.html [L]
```